# Function to convert all -ve numbers into their +ve counterparts without affecting present +ve values (-12 to 12)

Tags: data-analysis

I am essentially after a function that will convert negative values in my Excel spreadsheet into their positive equivalents without affecting the present positive values.

A sample of my data would be:-

-22.95361111111
-23.35000000000
0.25361111111
-0.14277777778
-0.53916666667
-0.93555555556

I have 43000 rows that I need to sort into ascending order but it is a miss-match of positive and negative values.

The data values give me a correlation in my data so the closer the value is to Zero, the more the data correlates, and i need to find all the values closest to Zero hence my request, as sorting the data currently does not yield a useful result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about the absolute value function?

Comment: I do not, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you are doing an excel formula, I believe you can do ABS(number) to return how far away a number is from 0.

Comment: For example, ABS(-12) gives 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do ABS(Number) in Excel to return how far a value is away from 0

Ex. -12 becomes 12 and 23 becomes 23 still